# Microstrategy reporting: Arabic data

Tags: report, arabic, business-intelligence, microstrategy

I am creating Microstrategy reports with prompts, however some of the prompt values are in Arabic and it's displayed as ????? in the prompt window. Is there any way t fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to modify the MicroStrategy Web Settings to have a font that supports also Arabic letters?

As mentioned in [General preferences](http://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/9.3/WebUser/WebHelp/Lang_1033/General_preferences.htm):

> **Font style**: Specify options for the fonts or typefaces that are
> applied to the interface and reports.
>
> **Note**: If you are using a double-byte (Asian) character set in the
> interface, be sure to select a font type that suits your language
> display.
>
> **Fonts**: Determine whether to use the default font settings or
> select specific fonts for use in Web. Select Custom to specify fonts.
> Once you select a font in the Available column, click the right arrow
> to move it to the Selected column. You can then select a font and
> click the up or down arrows to order them in the priority to use on
> reports. The default fonts are Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, and Microsoft
> Sans Serif.